# Centering a Checkbox vertically with other input components with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center a checkbox component styled with BootStrap, and I have not had any luck so far. I have tried using mt to specify different margin sizes so as to make it centered with a text input but none of the values fixes the problem.

This is how far I have come:

[image: CheckBox next to text input]

I have one form row, styled with the class "form-row", and two form-groups inside of it to group labels with their respective controls. It appears that, by default, a checkbox control is at the same height as a label for an input control (for example) when they are in a form group.

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
<div class="form-row col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label for="cuota">Cuota en litros</label>
                <input id="cuota" class="form-control" type="number" v-model.number="nuevaRuta.cuotaLitros">                
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-3 mt-5">                
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" v-model="nuevaRuta.activa" id="activa"/>                
                <label for="activa" class="mr-8 custom-control-label">Habilitar esta ruta</label>                           
              </div>
</div>
```

The closest I can come is to put it at the bottom baseline of other controls that are in the same row. I would like it it to be in the middle. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just group your inputs into **Flex** div rather then **row** and add **align-items-center** and also add some margin class to your **form-check** :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cuota">Cuota en litros</label>
    <input id="cuota" class="form-control" type="number" v-model.number="nuevaRuta.cuotaLitros">                
   </div>          
   <div class="form-check mt-3 ml-3">                
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" v-model="nuevaRuta.activa" id="activa"/>                
    <label for="activa" class="custom-control-label">Habilitar esta ruta</label>                           
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution works. I made some modifications to your code to make it the text input the same size as the other ones I have on my form, but the size is a bit off. Also, when I horizontally resize the browser, the label for the checkbox wraps to the next line even though there is more than enough space for the text. Do you know why that is? Thank you for the help, btw. Can you please also explain why your solution works? I do not quite understand why the checkboxes behave like that.

Comment: I modified the code for the checkbox div for this one:
<div class="form-check align-self-center col-sm-4 mt-3 ml-3">. Now the input text is the same size as the other ones in the form. No need to use d-flex since I use container in the div of the whole form (I guess that is why I do not need to use d-flex)

Comment: @Greg that's nice !! good solution !! yeh no need to  use **d-flex** since the **bootstrap grid** is based on  **flexbox** will just add **align-self-center** and it will be centred !! about your question if you want to manage your **children content** just set the parent to **flex** it will be easy for you to use !!

Answer (score 0):

You can just `align-items-center` add to the `form-row`...

```
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="cuota">Cuota en litros</label>
            <input id="cuota" class="form-control" type="number" v-model.number="nuevaRuta.cuotaLitros">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Habilitar esta ruta</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ZHmuMcBd1A

Comment: Your code didn't work. I want the whole checkbox with its label in the middle baseline of the text input that is right to the left of it.